# Sub-routes not working in separate file with koa-router

Tags: node.js, koa, koa-router

My `koa@next` app have the following structure. I'm using `koa-router@next` for the routing:

./app.js

```js
const Koa = require('koa');
const router = require('koa-router')();

const index = require('./routes/index');

const app = new Koa();

router.use('/', index.routes(), index.allowedMethods());
app
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods());

module.exports = app;
```

./routes/index.js

```js
const router = require('koa-router')();

router.get('/', (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = 'Frontpage';
});

router.get('/hello', (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = 'Hello, World!';
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm getting `Not Found` error on the `/hello` route.

Dependency versions:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "koa": "^2.0.0-alpha.7",
  "koa-router": "^7.0.1",
},
```

It's the same with `koa-router` v7.1.0.

Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restructuring the app like this solves the problem. I guess it's just really time to ditch Express mentally.

./app.js

```js
import Koa from 'koa';
import index from './routes/index';

const app = new Koa();

app.use(index.routes(), index.allowedMethods());

export default app;
```

./routes/index.js

```js
import Router from 'koa-router';

const router = new Router();
//const router = new Router({ prefix: '/subroute' })

router.get('/', (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = 'Frontpage';
});

router.get('/hello', (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = 'Hello, World!';
});

export default router;
```